# Problems with exponential equation

Tags: analysis

Solve the equation for $x,y \in (0,1)$

$$e^{-xy}=2y$$

I was told the function $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2| $ could help me here as we are listening to metric spaces right now but i am really clueless here. I hope you can help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one equation
in two unknowns,
so all you can do
is solve for one in
terms of the other,
or an equivalent.

If
$e^{-xy}=2y$,
you can solve for
$x$ in terms of
$y$ by
$e^{-x}=(2y)^{1/y}
$
or
$x
=-(\ln(2y))/y
$.

To solve for
$y$ in terms of $x$
looks like it would
involve the
Lambert W function.

I don't know what
the distance function
has to do with it.